# Pyright import from parent sibling results in missing import

Tags: python, pyright

I am trying to run a django app, and this is the following structure (minimal reproduction):

```
root/
  business/
    __init__.py
    urls.py
  monitoring/
    __init__.py
    api.py
  manage.py
```

In `urls.py` I have the following import: `from monitoring.api import MonitoringConfigurationAPIView`. However, this results in a Pyright error `[Pyright reportMissingImports] [E] Import "monitoring.api" could not be resolved`.

Adding a specifier to look in the parent directory (`from ..monitoring.api ...`) silences Pyright, but will cause Python itself to error out:

```
File "/home/user/Projects/root/business/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..monitoring.api import MonitoringConfigurationAPIView
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I've tried adding a blank `__init__.py` to the root, but that didn't help. I tried creating a `pyrightconfig.json` file in the root dir (`root/pyrightconfig.json`) and setting the root, but that too didn't work.

```
{
    "executionEnvironments": [
        {
          "root": "."
        }
    ]
}
```

All external packages it can handle just fine, no issues there. Only local are an issue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a link which pointed out my issue. `pyrightconfig.json` had to be at the repo root, not the project root.

> Just solved my issue. It seems the coc extension recognizes the root of your git repo as the root not the directory you open. I was using a subdirectory of a monorepo as my root and opening that with neovim on it's own. I just moved the pyrightconfig.json to the correct root and added the prefix of my sub-directory to the root path in an execution environment and it worked.

https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/235#issuecomment-756288634

My repo was technically

```
repo/
  namespace/
    namespace/
      django root/
        business/
        ...
```

I didn't think it mattered though. My mistake.